# iPhone app crashes when empty node is parsed

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I'm trying to parse an xml and the app crashes if there is an empty node in the xml feed.
What may be the reason for this?

**EDIT**
my xml looks like this

```
<Sponsors>
    <Sponsor>
        <Name>name...</Name>
        <About>blah...blah...blah</About>
        <Website>http://test.com</Website>
        <LogoImage>someImage.jpg</LogoImage>
        <smallIcon>someImage.jpg</smallIcon>
        <Area/>
        <BannerImage/>//->>>this node is empty//
     </Sponsor>
</Sponsors>
```

I'm using NSXML Parser like this.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
if(nil != self.currentsponsorElement){
    [self.currentsponsorElement appendString:string];
}
```

}

Comment: We'll need to see your xml and the code used to parse it. Are you checking for errors? What is the error?

Comment: @elppa yes, I'm using NSXML parsing

Comment: check ur  response data count in array / dictionary.

Comment: You can use a placeholder-string in foundCharacters and evaluate it within the ´didEndElement´ method.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

inside didStartElement use this code:-

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Sponsor"]) 
    {   
        if(!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; //declared in .h
        }
        recordResults = YES;
    }
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSMutableString *)string {

    if (string != nil) {
        [results setString:@""];
        [results appendString: string];
        NSLog(@"foundResults: %@",results);
    }

}
```

Comment: the parser parses with the content of the node printed in nslog, but crashes at the end.

Comment: though i have `NSZombie` enabled the nslog prints the contents of the xml but does not print what error caused the crash. the last few lines looks like this `2012-07-02 17:20:26.781 project[2164:4b03] foundResults: http://image1.jpg. 2012-07-02 17:20:26.781 project[2164:4b03] foundResults: 2012-07-02 17:20:26.781 BedFord[2164:4b03] foundResults: blah...blahh...`

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, I can only give you a general answer - it sounds like your code is "expecting" a value in the "parser:foundCharacters:" method. Go over your code and see what happens when the characters found are in fact nil. Use try-catch blocks and handle all possible scenarios so your code doen't cause crashes as a result of other things you still haven't thought of.